# How to access properties of objects from a third-party DOM library used in a React component from the outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I want to use Vis.js in a React based project. Since none of the Vis Network implementations work for me I have to use the plain library.

**This is my test React component**

```
import { DataSet, Network } from 'vis';
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";

class VisNetwork extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.network = {};
        this.appRef = createRef();
        this.nodes = new DataSet([
            { id: 1, label: 'Node 1' },
            { id: 2, label: 'Node 2' },
            { id: 3, label: 'Node 3' },
            { id: 4, label: 'Node 4' },
            { id: 5, label: 'Node 5' }
        ]);
        this.edges = new DataSet([
            { from: 1, to: 3 },
            { from: 1, to: 2 },
            { from: 2, to: 4 },
            { from: 2, to: 5 }
        ]);
        this.data = {
            nodes: this.nodes,
            edges: this.edges
        };
        this.options ={};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.network = new Network(this.appRef.current, this.data, this.options);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.appRef} />
        );
    }
}

export default VisNetwork;
```

**It's the only component mounted so far**

```
ReactDOM.render(<VisNetwork />,document.getElementById('mynetwork'));
```

My question is how I can access the properties of the network, for example, to get or delete a node.

```
node = nodes.get(nodeId);
```

I read about React Ref and tried something like
`() =>{ console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('vis-network'))` as callback of `ReactDOM.render()`but that doesn't help.

Another question is why isn't the ref not set and it's just `<div>`.

Because I thought that `this.appRef = createRef();` in the constructor of the component and `ref={this.appRef}` in render() would lead to a ref.

[image: Screenshot of debugger]

I hope you can give me a hint.

Comment: *why isn't the ref not set and it's just <div>* - what do you mean? What do you expect it to be set to? *tried and tried get something like* - where? Please, show this in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I added an info.

Comment: A ref of `<div>` is a div. It's still unclear about `document.getElementsByClassName('vis-network')`. Where did you do this? It's expected that you can access nested DOM with `this.appRef.current.querySelector(...)`. Of course, if you do this when elements don't exist yet, this won't work.

Comment: Found my mistake. Thought that ref={this.appRef} (in render()) will write a id in the div which I can select later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the flow should be the other way round, define the nodes outside of the component, then pass them in. For that define the constructor as:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.nodes = props.nodes;
    //...
}
```

Then construct it as:

```
 const nodes = new DataSet([/*...*/]);
 ReactDOM.render(<VisNetwork nodes={nodes} />,document.getElementById('mynetwork'));
```

Note that you should put anything stateful into `this.state` and use `setState` to mutate it.